# Proper combination of Arel nodes for Query with Subqueries in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

I'm trying to achieve the SQL with subquery below using Arel

```
students.classroom_id IN ( SELECT id FROM classrooms WHERE name IN ('foo', 'bar') )
```

I've tried the following combination

```
Student.arel_table[:classroom_id].in(
  Classroom.where(
    Classroom.arel_table[:name].in(
      ['foo', 'bar']
    )
  ).select(:id)
)
```

but when I execute `.to_sql` on that, it returns

```
students.classroom_id IN ( NULL NULL NULL NULL )
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my target output using the FF combination:

```
subquery = Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new Classroom.where(name: ['foo', 'bar'].select(:id).to_sql

Student.arel_table[:classroom_id].in(subquery)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you can't achieve this without Arel?

```
Student.where(classroom: Classroom.where(name: ['foo', 'bar']))
```

Comment: it is just a portion of a query, and I'll need to chain an "or" statement after that SQL, so I'm really aiming to do it using Arel.